# Instantiating server in Spring Framework 5 and Spring Boot 2

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am using `Spring Boot 2` just to try some reactive programming with Spring 5. I created some standard MVC controller.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/judge/rest")
public class BasicController {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BasicController.class);

    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public Mono<String> handle() {
        LOGGER.debug("Invoking hello controller");
        return Mono.just("Hello WebFlux");
    }

}
```

And standard router function.

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig {

    @Bean
    public RouterFunction<?> helloRoute() {
        return route(GET("/judge/router/hello"),
                request -> ServerResponse.ok().body(fromPublisher(Mono.just("Hello Router WebFlux"), String.class)));
    }

}
```

My main spring boot application looks like this

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class JudgeRuleEngineApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(JudgeRuleEngineApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

But in documentation for spring 5 I ran into

```
HttpHandler httpHandler = RouterFunctions.toHttpHandler(route);
ReactorHttpHandlerAdapter adapter =
  new ReactorHttpHandlerAdapter(httpHandler);
HttpServer server = HttpServer.create("localhost", 8080);
server.startAndAwait(adapter);
```

It seems that server is intantiated manually.

*My question is when should I instantiate the server like this?* Because so far it seems with `@SpringBootApplication` and `main` it handles requests just fine.

Comment: That is only needed if you don't use Spring Boot but only plain Spring. Spring Boot will detect the runtime (jetty, tomcat, netty, undertow) you want to use and configure web flux for it. As you already mentioned yourself you found that in the Spring Framework documentation and not in the Spring Boot documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the document says

> Now there is just one piece of the puzzle missing: running a router
>   function in an HTTP server. You can convert a router function into a
>   HttpHandler by using RouterFunctions.toHttpHandler(RouterFunction).
>   The HttpHandler allows you to run on a wide variety of reactive
>   runtimes: Reactor Netty, RxNetty, Servlet 3.1+, and Undertow.

Which means the above code which you have shown, uses Reactor Netty as the reactive runtime. If you wish to use any other runtimes which has reactive native adapter, you can do so. In such cases you would instantiate the server like this.

By default Spring boot default to Reactor Netty.

Comment: so basically router function in `webconfig` uses `netty` started by `spring boot`? and controller also uses it?

Comment: not only the router function, even the routes you created with traditional controller uses netty. As soonas springboot see's spring webflux or reactor dependency in your pom, it switches the container from default tomcat to netts. You can test this, by just removing the dependency from pom